# How to connect with pervasive database via php

Tags: php, pervasive-sql

I need to know how can I connect with pervasive database via php.

As I know, I have to use **ODBC**. I configured it on my *Windows 7* system and I created table in pervasive server.

This is my code, but it does not work:

```
$connect_string = "DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface}; SERVERNAME=localhost; SERVERDSN=demodata;";
$conn = odbc_connect($connect_string, 'root', 'root');
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?  What error are you getting?  The code looks correct. What version of Pervasive?  Where is the database located?  Is it on the same machine as the PHP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already have the ODBC drivers installed; I obtained the latest by installing the Pervasive Client from http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv12.aspx (current version is 12).

Then depending on 32 or 64 bit use the following connection string:

32bit:

```
$connect=odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=DSNname;",
    "Username", "Password", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

64bit:

```
$connect=odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=DSNname;",
    "Username", "Password", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

(You can check these strings with the ODBC data source administrator on Windows, use equivalent on other operating systems).

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string:

```
$connect=odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=DSNname;",
    "Username", "Password", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

Comment: I tried ODBC Engine interface but the ODBC Data Source Administrator under Administrator Tools suggest me that Engine Interfaces are deprecated nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1"; $username = "root"; $password = "password";$db ="database";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```